# Why dispatchEvent of JavaScript does not work on IOS mobile app?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, iphone

This code is written for the login at a modem page. It works if I run it through the browser or it works through the mobile browser. I connect my iPhone via developer mode that provided by Safari -please see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html) to see how to connect it- and it works there too.

And, I have a mobile app and would like to run it over the mobile app's browser that runs in the background.

However, although it works on each platform, this code does not work on the mobile.

Any guess?

Here is the code:

```
var sendcode = function(elementId,str){
    var elmnt=document.getElementById(elementId);
    var instr='';
    for(let chr of str){
    let kei={ key:chr,code:'Key'+chr.toUpperCase(), bubbles: true, composed: true, 
              cancelable: true, eventPhase: 3, isComposing: false,isTrusted: true, 
              view:document.defaultView, which:chr.charCodeAt(0)};

    instr += chr;
    let iei={ inputType:'insertText', data:instr, bubbles: true};

    elmnt.value=instr;
    iev= new InputEvent('input',iei);
    elmnt.dispatchEvent(iev);
    }
}
sendcode('username','admin');
sendcode('userpassword','password');
```

Additionally, when I debug it, it gets angry by "dispatchEvent". But, without it, it does not useful for the job that I want to do.